# GNU MAKE can not find system header files

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, header-files

My code contains
`#include <string.h>`
which means it is trying to include system header files this header file is in /usr/include but make command can not find it.
My operating system is ubuntu 12.04
GNU MAKE version is 3.81
and the error is 
fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory
 #include

if i give full path like /usr/include/string.h then it will find it but inside string.h there are other includes like features.h the same problem occurs again and the same goes for the includes inside features.h can someone tell me how to include /usr/include in header files search path. Thanks

$ cpp -v /dev/null

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=cpp
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch i386-linux-gnu /dev/null -mtune=generic -march=i686 -fstack-protector
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/i386-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
# 1 "/dev/null"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/dev/null"
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../i386-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/:/lib/i386-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
```

Make file content:

```
NDK_PATH=$(shell dirname `which ndk-build`)
NDK_MAJOR_VERSION=$(shell cat $(NDK_PATH)/RELEASE.TXT | sed "s/r\([0-9]\{1,2\}\).*/\1/")
SDK_PATH=$(shell dirname `which android`)
SDK_PLATFORM_TOOLS_PATH=$(shell dirname `which adb`)
ARM_COMPILER_PATH=`find "$(NDK_PATH)" -name "arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4*" -print | tail -1`
ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH=$(shell dirname $(ARM_COMPILER_PATH))/arm-linux-androideabi-
X86_COMPILER_PATH=`find "$(NDK_PATH)" -name "i686-linux-android-gcc-4*" -print | tail -1`
X86_TOOLCHAIN_PATH=$(shell dirname $(X86_COMPILER_PATH))/i686-linux-android-
NUMCPUS=$(shell grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || echo "4" )
TOPDIR=$(shell pwd)
LIBLINPHONE_VERSION=$(shell cd submodules/linphone && git describe --always)
LINPHONE_ANDROID_DEBUG_VERSION=$(shell git describe --always)
BELLESIP_VERSION_SCRIPT:=cat submodules/belle-sip/configure.ac | grep "AC_INIT(" | sed -e "s/.*belle-sip\]//" | sed -e "s/].*//" | sed -e "s/.*\[//"
BELLESIP_VERSION=$(shell $(BELLESIP_VERSION_SCRIPT))
ANDROID_MOST_RECENT_TARGET=$(shell android list target -c | grep -E 'android-[0-9]+' | tail -n1)
#We force target 19 because 21 creates binaries incompatible with older versions due to rand() function no longer inline (congrats to Google's developers)
NDKBUILD_TARGET=android-10
#The NDK target used to compile external third parties (ffmpeg, x264)
EXTERNAL_MAKE_TARGET=14
ARM_SYSROOT=${NDK_PATH}/platforms/android-$(EXTERNAL_MAKE_TARGET)/arch-arm
X86_SYSROOT=${NDK_PATH}/platforms/android-$(EXTERNAL_MAKE_TARGET)/arch-x86
SQLITE_VERSION=3071700
SQLITE_BASENAME=sqlite-amalgamation-$(SQLITE_VERSION)
SQLITE_URL=http://www.sqlite.org/2013/$(SQLITE_BASENAME).zip
ENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES=1
#override CC variable to disable compiler specific FLAGS in configure using the system compiler instead of the android one
CC=
PACKAGE_NAME=$(shell sed -nE 's|<property name="linphone.package.name" value="(.*)" />|\1|p' custom_rules.xml)
#default options, can be overidden using make OPTION=value .

ifeq ($(ENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES),1)
BUILD_G729=1
else
#x264 and g729 requires additional licensing agreements.
BUILD_X264=0
BUILD_G729=0
endif

NDK_DEBUG=0
BUILD_VIDEO=0
BUILD_OPENH264=0
BUILD_NON_FREE_CODECS=1
ENABLE_OPENH264_DECODER=0
BUILD_UPNP=1
BUILD_AMRNB=full # 0, light or full
BUILD_AMRWB=1
BUILD_ZRTP=1
BUILD_SILK=1
BUILD_TUNNEL=0
BUILD_WEBRTC_AECM=1
BUILD_OPUS=1
BUILD_MATROSKA=1
BUILD_WEBRTC_ISAC=1
BUILD_FOR_X86=1
BUILD_FOR_ARM=1
USE_JAVAH=1
BUILD_TLS=1
BUILD_SQLITE=1
BUILD_CONTACT_HEADER=0
BUILD_RTP_MAP=0
BUILD_DONT_CHECK_HEADERS_IN_MESSAGE=0
BUILD_ILBC=1
LIBLINPHONE_EXTENDED_SRC_FILES=
LIBLINPHONE_EXTENDED_C_INCLUDES=
LIBLINPHONE_EXTENDED_CFLAGS=
APP_STL=stlport_static
ANT_SILENT=$(shell ant -h | grep -q -- -S && echo 1 || echo 0)

# Checks
CHECK_MSG=$(shell ./check_tools.sh)

ifneq ($(CHECK_MSG),)
    $(error Some tools are missing.)
else
    ifeq ($(BUILD_OPENH264),1)
        ifneq ($(shell echo $(NDK_MAJOR_VERSION)\>=10 | bc),1)
$(error ndk version [$(NDK_MAJOR_VERSION)] not compatible with openh264.)
        endif
    endif
    include check_tools.mk
endif

OPENSSL_DIR=$(shell openssl version -d | sed  "s/OPENSSLDIR: \"\(.*\)\"/\1/")
ifneq ($(shell ls $(OPENSSL_DIR)/certs),)
    HTTPS_CA_DIR=$(OPENSSL_DIR)/certs
else
    HTTPS_CA_DIR=$(OPENSSL_DIR)
endif

ifeq ($(ANT_SILENT), 1)
    ANT=ant -e -S
else
    ANT=ant -e
endif

# Temporary check: in case of MediastreamActivity.java file existing while it should not anymore, print an error message
# and abort build since otherwise java compilation will fail.
ifneq ($(shell ls ./submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java/src/org/linphone/mediastream/MediastreamerActivity.java 2>/dev/null),)
$(error ./submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java/src/org/linphone/mediastream/MediastreamerActivity.java found: please either remove it or move it to MediastreamActivity.java.ignored before continuing.)
endif

ifeq ($(BUILD_NON_FREE_CODECS), 0)
BUILD_OPENH264=0
ENABLE_OPENH264_DECODER=0
BUILD_AMRNB=0
BUILD_AMRWB=0
BUILD_G729=0
BUILD_X264=0
endif

all: update-project generate-apk
ifeq ($(ENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES),1)
    @echo "***************************************************************************"
    @echo "***** CAUTION, this liblinphone SDK is built using 3rd party GPL code *****"
    @echo "*****    Even if you acquired a proprietary license from Belledonne   *****"
    @echo "*****          Communications, this SDK is GPL and GPL only.          *****"
    @echo "*****           To disable 3rd party gpl code, please use:            *****"
    @echo "*****                 $$ make ENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES=0               *****"
    @echo "***************************************************************************"
else
    @echo
    @echo "*****************************************************************"
    @echo "*****      Linphone SDK without 3rd party GPL software      *****"
    @echo "***** If you acquired a proprietary license from Belledonne *****"
    @echo "*****     Communications, this SDK can be used to create    *****"
    @echo "*****       a proprietary linphone-based application.       *****"
    @echo "*****************************************************************"
endif

install: install-apk run-linphone

#libilbc
LIBILBC_SRC_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/libilbc-rfc3951
LIBILBC_BUILD_DIR=$(LIBILBC_SRC_DIR)
$(LIBILBC_SRC_DIR)/configure:
    cd $(LIBILBC_SRC_DIR) && ./autogen.sh

$(LIBILBC_BUILD_DIR)/Makefile: $(LIBILBC_SRC_DIR)/configure
    cd $(LIBILBC_BUILD_DIR) && \
    ./configure \

$(LIBILBC_BUILD_DIR)/src/iLBC_decode.c: $(LIBILBC_BUILD_DIR)/Makefile
    cd $(LIBILBC_BUILD_DIR)/downloads && make \
    || ( echo "iLBC prepare stage failed" ; exit 1 )

ifeq ($(BUILD_ILBC),1)
prepare-ilbc: $(LIBILBC_BUILD_DIR)/src/iLBC_decode.c
else
prepare-ilbc:
endif

#ffmpeg
ifeq ($(BUILD_VIDEO),1)
BUILD_FFMPEG_DEPS=$(FFMPEG_SRC_DIR)/non_versioned_soname_patch_applied.txt $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm/libffmpeg-linphone-arm.so
ifeq ($(BUILD_FOR_X86), 1)
    BUILD_FFMPEG_DEPS+=$(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86/libffmpeg-linphone-x86.so
endif
endif
FFMPEG_SRC_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/ffmpeg
FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/build/ffmpeg
FFMPEG_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=--target-os=linux --enable-cross-compile --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
    --disable-everything --disable-doc --disable-ffplay --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-swresample --disable-network \
    --enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-encoder=mjpeg --enable-decoder=mpeg4 --enable-encoder=mpeg4 --enable-decoder=h264 \
    --enable-decoder=h263p --enable-encoder=h263p --enable-decoder=h263 --enable-encoder=h263 --extra-cflags="-w" \
    --disable-static --enable-shared --disable-symver
FFMPEG_ARM_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=--build-suffix=-linphone-arm --arch=arm --sysroot=$(ARM_SYSROOT) --cross-prefix=$(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH) --enable-pic
FFMPEG_X86_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=--build-suffix=-linphone-x86 --arch=x86 --sysroot=$(X86_SYSROOT) --cross-prefix=$(X86_TOOLCHAIN_PATH) --disable-mmx --disable-sse2 --disable-ssse3 --extra-cflags='-O3'

$(FFMPEG_SRC_DIR)/non_versioned_soname_patch_applied.txt:
    @patch -p0 < $(TOPDIR)/patches/ffmpeg_non_versioned_soname.patch
    touch $@

$(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm/config.h:
    mkdir -p $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm && \
    cd $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm && \
    $(FFMPEG_SRC_DIR)/configure $(FFMPEG_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS) $(FFMPEG_ARM_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS)
    sed -i.bak 's/#define HAVE_SYSCTL 1/#define HAVE_SYSCTL 0/g' $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm/config.h
    sed -i.bak 's/#define HAVE_GETHRTIME 1/#define HAVE_GETHRTIME 0/g' $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm/config.h

$(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm/libavcodec/libavcodec-linphone-arm.so: $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm/config.h
    cd $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm && \
    make -j${NUMCPUS} \
    || ( echo "Build of ffmpeg for arm failed." ; exit 1 )

$(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm/libffmpeg-linphone-arm.so: $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm/libavcodec/libavcodec-linphone-arm.so
    cd $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm && \
    rm libavcodec/log2_tab.o && \
    $(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH)gcc -lm -lz --sysroot=$(ARM_SYSROOT) -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared libavutil/*.o libavutil/arm/*.o libavcodec/*.o libavcodec/arm/*.o libswscale/*.o -o libffmpeg-linphone-arm.so

$(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86/config.h:
    mkdir -p $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86 && \
    cd $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86 && \
    $(FFMPEG_SRC_DIR)/configure $(FFMPEG_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS) $(FFMPEG_X86_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS)
    sed -i.bak 's/#define HAVE_SYSCTL 1/#define HAVE_SYSCTL 0/g' $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86/config.h
    sed -i.bak 's/#define HAVE_GETHRTIME 1/#define HAVE_GETHRTIME 0/g' $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86/config.h

$(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86/libavcodec/libavcodec-linphone-x86.so: $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86/config.h
    cd $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86 && \
    make -j${NUMCPUS} \
    || ( echo "Build of ffmpeg for x86 failed." ; exit 1 )

$(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86/libffmpeg-linphone-x86.so: $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86/libavcodec/libavcodec-linphone-x86.so
    cd $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86 && \
    rm libavcodec/log2_tab.o && \
    $(X86_TOOLCHAIN_PATH)gcc -lm -lz --sysroot=$(X86_SYSROOT) -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared libavutil/*.o libavutil/x86/*.o libavcodec/*.o libavcodec/x86/*.o libswscale/*.o -o  libffmpeg-linphone-x86.so

build-ffmpeg: $(BUILD_FFMPEG_DEPS)

clean-ffmpeg:
    rm -rf $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/arm && \
    rm -rf $(FFMPEG_BUILD_DIR)/x86

#x264
ifeq ($(BUILD_VIDEO),1)
ifeq ($(BUILD_X264), 1)
BUILD_X264_DEPS=$(X264_SRC_DIR)/log2f_fix_patch_applied.txt $(X264_BUILD_DIR)/arm/libx264.a
ifeq ($(BUILD_FOR_X86), 1)
    BUILD_X264_DEPS+=$(X264_BUILD_DIR)/x86/libx264.a
endif
endif

X264_SRC_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/x264
X264_BUILD_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/build/x264
X264_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=--enable-static
X264_ARM_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=--host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --sysroot=$(ARM_SYSROOT) --cross-prefix=$(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH) --enable-pic
X264_X86_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=--host=i686-linux-gnueabi --sysroot=$(X86_SYSROOT) --cross-prefix=$(X86_TOOLCHAIN_PATH)

$(X264_SRC_DIR)/log2f_fix_patch_applied.txt:
    @patch -p0 < $(TOPDIR)/patches/x264_log2f_fix.patch
    touch $@

$(X264_BUILD_DIR)/arm/libx264.a:
    mkdir -p $(X264_BUILD_DIR)/arm && \
    cd $(X264_SRC_DIR) && \
    $(X264_SRC_DIR)/configure $(X264_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS) $(X264_ARM_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS) && \
    make -j$(NUMCPUS) STRIP= && \
    cp libx264.a $(X264_BUILD_DIR)/arm/libx264.a && \
    make clean \
    || ( echo "Build of x264 for arm failed." ; exit 1 )

$(X264_BUILD_DIR)/x86/libx264.a:
    mkdir -p $(X264_BUILD_DIR)/x86 && \
    cd $(X264_SRC_DIR) && \
    $(X264_SRC_DIR)/configure $(X264_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS) $(X264_X86_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS) && \
    make -j$(NUMCPUS) STRIP= && \
    cp libx264.a $(X264_BUILD_DIR)/x86/libx264.a && \
    make clean \
    || ( echo "Build of x264 for x86 failed." ; exit 1 )

endif
build-x264: $(BUILD_X264_DEPS)

clean-x264:
    rm -rf $(X264_BUILD_DIR)/arm && \
    rm -rf $(X264_BUILD_DIR)/x86

#openh264
ifeq ($(BUILD_VIDEO),1)
ifeq ($(BUILD_OPENH264), 1)
BUILD_OPENH264_DEPS=build-openh264-arm
ifeq ($(BUILD_FOR_X86), 1)
    BUILD_OPENH264_DEPS+=build-openh264-x86
endif
endif
endif

OPENH264_SRC_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/openh264
OPENH264_BUILD_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/build/openh264
OPENH264_BUILD_DIR_ARM=$(OPENH264_BUILD_DIR)/arm
OPENH264_BUILD_DIR_X86=$(OPENH264_BUILD_DIR)/x86

$(OPENH264_SRC_DIR)/patch.stamp: $(TOPDIR)/patches/openh264-permissive.patch
    cd $(OPENH264_SRC_DIR) && patch -p1 < $(TOPDIR)/patches/openh264-permissive.patch && touch $(OPENH264_SRC_DIR)/patch.stamp

openh264-patch: $(OPENH264_SRC_DIR)/patch.stamp

openh264-install-headers:
    mkdir -p $(OPENH264_SRC_DIR)/include/wels
    rsync -rvLpgoc --exclude ".git"  $(OPENH264_SRC_DIR)/codec/api/svc/* $(OPENH264_SRC_DIR)/include/wels/.

copy-openh264-x86: openh264-patch openh264-install-headers
    mkdir -p $(OPENH264_BUILD_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(OPENH264_BUILD_DIR_X86)
    cd $(OPENH264_BUILD_DIR_X86) \
    && rsync -rvLpgoc --exclude ".git"  $(OPENH264_SRC_DIR)/* .

copy-openh264-arm: openh264-patch openh264-install-headers
    mkdir -p $(OPENH264_BUILD_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(OPENH264_BUILD_DIR_ARM)
    cd $(OPENH264_BUILD_DIR_ARM) \
    && rsync -rvLpgoc --exclude ".git"  $(OPENH264_SRC_DIR)/* .

build-openh264-x86: copy-openh264-x86
    cd $(OPENH264_BUILD_DIR_X86) && \
    make libraries -j$(NUMCPUS) OS=android ARCH=x86 NDKROOT=$(NDK_PATH) TARGET=$(NDKBUILD_TARGET)

build-openh264-arm: copy-openh264-arm
    cd $(OPENH264_BUILD_DIR_ARM) && \
    make libraries -j$(NUMCPUS) OS=android ARCH=arm NDKROOT=$(NDK_PATH) TARGET=$(NDKBUILD_TARGET)

build-openh264: $(BUILD_OPENH264_DEPS)

clean-openh264:
    cd $(OPENH264_SRC_DIR) && git clean -dfx && git reset --hard
    rm -rf $(OPENH264_BUILD_DIR_ARM)
    rm -rf $(OPENH264_BUILD_DIR_X86)

#libvpx
ifeq ($(BUILD_VIDEO),1)
BUILD_VPX_DEPS=$(LIBVPX_SRC_DIR)/configure_android_x86_patch_applied.txt $(LIBVPX_BUILD_DIR)/arm/libvpx.a
ifeq ($(BUILD_FOR_X86), 1)
    BUILD_VPX_DEPS+=$(LIBVPX_BUILD_DIR)/x86/libvpx.a
endif
endif
LIBVPX_SRC_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/libvpx
LIBVPX_BUILD_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/build/libvpx
LIBVPX_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=--disable-vp9 --disable-examples --disable-unit-tests --disable-postproc --enable-error-concealment --enable-debug

$(LIBVPX_SRC_DIR)/configure_android_x86_patch_applied.txt:
    @patch -p1 < $(TOPDIR)/patches/libvpx_configure_android_x86.patch
    touch $@

$(LIBVPX_BUILD_DIR)/arm/libvpx.a:
    mkdir -p $(LIBVPX_BUILD_DIR)/arm && \
    cd $(LIBVPX_BUILD_DIR)/arm && \
    $(LIBVPX_SRC_DIR)/configure --target=armv7-android-gcc --sdk-path=$(NDK_PATH) $(LIBVPX_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS) && \
    make -j${NUMCPUS} \
    || ( echo "Build of libvpx for arm failed." ; exit 1 )

$(LIBVPX_BUILD_DIR)/x86/libvpx.a:
    mkdir -p $(LIBVPX_BUILD_DIR)/x86 && \
    cd $(LIBVPX_BUILD_DIR)/x86 && \
    $(LIBVPX_SRC_DIR)/configure --target=x86-android-gcc --sdk-path=$(NDK_PATH) $(LIBVPX_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS) && \
    make -j${NUMCPUS} \
    || ( echo "Build of libvpx for x86 failed." ; exit 1 )

build-vpx: $(BUILD_VPX_DEPS)

clean-vpx:
    cd $(LIBVPX_SRC_DIR) && git clean -dfx && git reset --hard
    rm -rf submodules/externals/build/libvpx/arm && \
    rm -rf submodules/externals/build/libvpx/x86




#srtp
$(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/srtp/config.h : $(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/build/srtp/config.h
    @cd $(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/srtp/ && \
    cp ../build/srtp/config.h . \
    || ( echo "SRTP prepare state failed." ; exit 1 )

prepare-srtp: $(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/srtp/config.h

#ms2
prepare-mediastreamer2:
    @cd $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/src/ && \
    eval `cat Makefile.am | grep xxd | grep yuv2rgb.vs | sed 's/\$$(abs_builddir)/./'` && \
    eval `cat Makefile.am | grep xxd | grep yuv2rgb.fs | sed 's/\$$(abs_builddir)/./'` && \
    if ! [ -e yuv2rgb.vs.h ]; then echo "yuv2rgb.vs.h creation error (do you have 'xxd' application installed ?)"; exit 1; fi && \
    if ! [ -e yuv2rgb.fs.h ]; then echo "yuv2rgb.fs.h creation error (do you have 'xxd' application installed ?)"; exit 1; fi

#antlr3
ANLTR3_SRC_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/antlr3/runtime/C/include/
ANTLR3_BUILD_DIR=$(ANTLR3_SRC_DIR)
$(ANLTR3_SRC_DIR)/antlr3config.h: $(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/build/antlr3/antlr3config.h
    cp $(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/build/antlr3/antlr3config.h $(ANLTR3_SRC_DIR)
prepare-antlr3: $(ANLTR3_SRC_DIR)/antlr3config.h

%.tokens: %.g
    $(ANTLR) -make -fo $(dir $^) $^

#Belle-sip
BELLESIP_SRC_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/belle-sip
BELLESIP_BUILD_DIR=$(BELLESIP_SRC_DIR)
prepare-belle-sip: $(BELLESIP_SRC_DIR)/src/grammars/belle_sip_message.tokens $(BELLESIP_SRC_DIR)/src/grammars/belle_sdp.tokens

#CUnit
prepare-cunit: $(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/cunit/CUnit/Headers/*.h
    [ -d $(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/build/cunit/CUnit ] || mkdir $(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/build/cunit/CUnit
    cp $^ $(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/build/cunit/CUnit

$(TOPDIR)/res/raw/rootca.pem:
     HTTPS_CA_DIR=$(HTTPS_CA_DIR) $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/scripts/mk-ca-bundle.pl $@

prepare-liblinphone_tester: $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/tester/tester_hosts $(TOPDIR)/res/raw/rootca.pem $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/tester/messages.db
    rm -rf liblinphone_tester/assets/config_files
    mkdir -p liblinphone_tester/assets/config_files
    for file in $^; do \
    cp -rf $$file $(TOPDIR)/liblinphone_tester/assets/config_files/. \
    ;done
    cp -rf $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/tester/certificates $(TOPDIR)/liblinphone_tester/assets/config_files
    cp -rf $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/tester/sounds $(TOPDIR)/liblinphone_tester/assets/config_files
    cp -rf $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/tester/images $(TOPDIR)/liblinphone_tester/assets/config_files
    cp -rf $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/tester/rcfiles $(TOPDIR)/liblinphone_tester/assets/config_files


#Matroska2
MATROSKA_SRC_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/libmatroska
MATROSKA_BUILD_DIR=$(TOPDIR)/submodules/externals/build/libmatroska
ifeq ($(BUILD_MATROSKA), 1)
prepare-matroska2: $(MATROSKA_SRC_DIR)/patch_applied.txt
else
prepare-matroska2:
endif

$(MATROSKA_SRC_DIR)/patch_applied.txt: $(MATROSKA_BUILD_DIR)/fix_libmatroska2.patch
    cd $(MATROSKA_SRC_DIR); patch -p1 < $<; touch $@

#Build targets
prepare-sources: build-ffmpeg build-x264 build-openh264 prepare-ilbc build-vpx prepare-srtp prepare-mediastreamer2 prepare-antlr3 prepare-belle-sip $(TOPDIR)/res/raw/rootca.pem prepare-matroska2

GENERATE_OPTIONS = NDK_DEBUG=$(NDK_DEBUG) BUILD_FOR_X86=$(BUILD_FOR_X86) \
    BUILD_AMRNB=$(BUILD_AMRNB) BUILD_AMRWB=$(BUILD_AMRWB) BUILD_SILK=$(BUILD_SILK) BUILD_G729=$(BUILD_G729) BUILD_OPUS=$(BUILD_OPUS) \
    BUILD_VIDEO=$(BUILD_VIDEO) BUILD_X264=$(BUILD_X264) BUILD_OPENH264=$(BUILD_OPENH264) ENABLE_OPENH264_DECODER=$(ENABLE_OPENH264_DECODER) BUILD_MATROSKA=$(BUILD_MATROSKA) \
    BUILD_UPNP=$(BUILD_UPNP) BUILD_ZRTP=$(BUILD_ZRTP) BUILD_WEBRTC_AECM=$(BUILD_WEBRTC_AECM) BUILD_WEBRTC_ISAC=$(BUILD_WEBRTC_ISAC) BUILD_ILBC=$(BUILD_ILBC) \
    BUILD_FOR_ARM=$(BUILD_FOR_ARM) BUILD_NON_FREE_CODECS=$(BUILD_NON_FREE_CODECS)


LIBLINPHONE_OPTIONS = $(GENERATE_OPTIONS) \
    LIBLINPHONE_VERSION=$(LIBLINPHONE_VERSION) BELLESIP_VERSION=$(BELLESIP_VERSION) USE_JAVAH=$(USE_JAVAH) \
    BUILD_TUNNEL=$(BUILD_TUNNEL) BUILD_TLS=$(BUILD_TLS) BUILD_SQLITE=$(BUILD_SQLITE) \
    BUILD_CONTACT_HEADER=$(BUILD_CONTACT_HEADER) BUILD_RTP_MAP=$(BUILD_RTP_MAP) \
    LIBLINPHONE_EXTENDED_SRC_FILES="$(LIBLINPHONE_EXTENDED_SRC_FILES)" \
    LIBLINPHONE_EXTENDED_C_INCLUDES="$(LIBLINPHONE_EXTENDED_C_INCLUDES)" \
    LIBLINPHONE_EXTENDED_CFLAGS="$(LIBLINPHONE_EXTENDED_CFLAGS)" \
    APP_STL="$(APP_STL)" \
    BUILD_DONT_CHECK_HEADERS_IN_MESSAGE=$(BUILD_DONT_CHECK_HEADERS_IN_MESSAGE)

MEDIASTREAMER2_OPTIONS = $(GENERATE_OPTIONS) BUILD_MEDIASTREAMER2_SDK=1


generate-libs: prepare-sources javah
    $(NDK_PATH)/ndk-build $(LIBLINPHONE_OPTIONS) -j$(NUMCPUS) TARGET_PLATFORM=$(NDKBUILD_TARGET)

generate-mediastreamer2-libs: prepare-sources
    @cd $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java && \
    $(NDK_PATH)/ndk-build $(MEDIASTREAMER2_OPTIONS) -j$(NUMCPUS) TARGET_PLATFORM=$(NDKBUILD_TARGET)

update-project: $(TOPDIR)/res/raw/rootca.pem
    $(SDK_PATH)/android update project --path . --target $(ANDROID_MOST_RECENT_TARGET)
    $(SDK_PATH)/android update test-project --path tests -m .
    $(SDK_PATH)/android update project --path liblinphone_tester --target $(ANDROID_MOST_RECENT_TARGET)

update-mediastreamer2-project:
    @cd $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java && \
    $(SDK_PATH)/android update project --path . --target $(ANDROID_MOST_RECENT_TARGET)

liblinphone_tester: update-project prepare-sources prepare-cunit prepare-liblinphone_tester javah
    $(NDK_PATH)/ndk-build -C liblinphone_tester $(LIBLINPHONE_OPTIONS) -j$(NUMCPUS) TARGET_PLATFORM=$(NDKBUILD_TARGET)
    $(MAKE) -C liblinphone_tester

javah:
    $(ANT) javah

generate-apk: java-clean generate-libs
    echo "version.name=$(LINPHONE_ANDROID_DEBUG_VERSION)" > default.properties
    $(ANT) debug

generate-mediastreamer2-apk: java-clean generate-mediastreamer2-libs
    @cd $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java && \
    echo "version.name=$(LINPHONE_ANDROID_DEBUG_VERSION)" > default.properties && \
    $(ANT) debug

uninstall:
    adb uninstall $(PACKAGE_NAME)

install-apk:
    ant installd

release: update-project
    $(ANT) clean
    patch -p1 < release.patch
    cat ant.properties | grep version.name > default.properties
    $(ANT) release
    patch -Rp1 < release.patch

run-linphone:
    ant run

run-liblinphone-tests: liblinphone_tester
    $(MAKE) -C liblinphone_tester run-all-tests

run-basic-tests: update-project
    $(ANT) partial-clean
    $(MAKE) -C tests run-basic-tests ANT_SILENT=$(ANT_SILENT)

run-all-tests: update-project
    $(ANT) partial-clean
    $(MAKE) -C tests run-all-tests ANT_SILENT=$(ANT_SILENT)

clean-ndk-build:
    - $(NDK_PATH)/ndk-build clean $(LIBLINPHONE_OPTIONS)
    $(ANT) clean
    @if [ -f $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java/project.properties ]; then \
      cd $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java && $(ANT) clean; \
    fi

.NOTPARALLEL clean-native: clean-ndk-build clean-ffmpeg clean-x264 clean-openh264 clean-vpx


java-clean:
    $(ANT) clean

clean:  clean-native java-clean

veryclean: clean

.PHONY: clean install-apk run-linphone

generate-sdk: liblinphone-android-sdk

liblinphone-android-sdk: generate-apk
    $(ANT) liblinphone-android-sdk

linphone-android-sdk: generate-apk
    $(ANT) linphone-android-sdk

mediastreamer2-sdk: update-mediastreamer2-project generate-mediastreamer2-apk
    @cd $(TOPDIR)/submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java && \
    $(ANT) mediastreamer2-sdk

pull-transifex:
    tx pull -af

push-transifex:
    tx push -s -t -f --no-interactive
```

Comment: Please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting guidelines.

Comment: `make` has nothing to do with finding include files, that's the preprocessor's job. Add output of `cpp -v /dev/null` to your question. Did you install `gcc`from the official package sources of your distribution?

Comment: echo $PATH :
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/media/ubuntu/android/android-ndk-r10e

Comment: i added cpp -v /dev/null output and yes gcc is default package that is installed in ubuntu thanks.

Comment: This looks good (`/usr/include` is in the search list) ... could you also add how you invoke `gcc` from your `Makefile`? You could try to compile a simple "helloworld.c" directly calling `gcc`...

Comment: i compiled a simple c code it compiled successfully. it seems the problem is not with make but somewhere else. I am exporting NDK path but it gives bash: ndk-build=./media/ubuntu/android/android-ndk-r10e: No such file or directory on terminal start do you thinks it can cause the issue.

Comment: What are you trying here? If your target is an android device, you need a *cross toolchain* -- your system `gcc` cannot create code for android arm-eabi.

Comment: @AbdulMusawer oh wow .. added android-ndk tag here, maybe someone over there can help -- looks like it isn't installed correctly.

Comment: @FelixPalmen thanks for your time and effort . solved the problem it was some path and script permission problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with SDK , NDK paths and permission problem with some of the scripts in the submodules.
1. paths are corrected in ~/.bashrc
2. the various scripts permission were corrected with chmod